# PHP Search fetch where data exist in fields

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to create a search, anyways my site is:

```
mysite.com/?p=search&t=[SEARCH VARIABLE]
```

So for in my case if my url is that I want it to search through my table of posts and give me the results where `[SEARCH VARIABLE]` exists in the table. Mainly I want it to check these columns: title, content and author. If there is any [Search variable] in there I want it to show up.

Attempt that works [with only 1 column] but does not give me all the results.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['t']))
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `title` like :t');
    echo ' <h1>Search results for: '.$_GET['t'].'</h1> ';
    if (!$stmt->execute(array(':t' => $_GET['t'])))
    {
        exit('Could not exec query with param: '.$_GET['t']);
    }

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '<font size="4pt">'.$row["title"].'</font><br>
                        ';

    }
    }
 ?>
```

My attempt the same as the first one but checks the content field. Does not work either.

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_GET['t']))
    {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `title` like :t AND `content` like :t;');
        echo ' <h1>Search results for: '.$_GET['t'].'</h1> ';
        if (!$stmt->execute(array(':t' => $_GET['t'])))
        {
            exit('Could not exec query with param: '.$_GET['t']);
        }

        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            echo '<font size="4pt">'.$row["title"].'</font><br>
                            ';
        }
    }
  ?>
```

With the first one, it only shows one field with the title of it. But I want it to show anything with the word in it. For example if you search for "hey' and have "hey theres apples", i want it to show that hey theres apples.

EDIT:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['t']))
{

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `title` like %:t%');

    echo ' <h1>Search results for: '.$_GET['t'].'</h1> ';

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '<font size="4pt">'.$row["title"].'</font><br>
                        ';

                            }
                            }

                    ?>
```

Still needing help.

Comment: @яша There is no error, its just not showing. With the first one, it only shows one field with the title of it. But I want it to show anything with the word in it. For example if you search for "hey' and have "hey theres apples", i want it to show that hey theres apples.

Comment: @JakeGould No, I dont see the answer on that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not placing `LIKE` wildcards (`%`) around the search terms. Without wildcards, the query will look for the literal terms in your params which is not really what you’d want to use `LIKE` for.

So a statement like this:

```
$stmt->execute(array(':t' => $_GET['t'])
```

Would be this instead:

```
$stmt->execute(array(':t' => '"%'.$_GET['t'].'%"')
```

**EDIT** Perhaps doing it this way would be better. Leave your code as the original question, ignore the changes above and adjust your statements like this:

```
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `title` like %:t%');
```

Also for your combined statement do a similar changed and perhaps change that `AND` to an `OR`:

```
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `title` like %:t% OR `content` like %:t%;');
```

But somehow you need those wildcards in place to get the results you are implying by the question.

Comment: Im afraid this did not work.